# SQL Server : select how to?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table and I need to get unique rows with latest called_date but adding phones to the right if phones do not match but name is the same. There could be even more different phones with the same name. I need to add them all to the right. I am working on it all day. Is it even possible? How to do that?

Database is SQL Server. This example on excel is just for show.

[image: difficult select]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it'd be nice to have some nicely formatted sample data to use:

```
SELECT 
    * 
INTO ##CallData
FROM
(
    SELECT '1245' as ID, 555963 as Phone, '2014-11-01' as Called_date, 'some_name' as Name, 'some@gmail.com' as Email
    UNION
    SELECT '5896' as ID, 896111 as Phone, '2014-11-05' as Called_date, 'other_name' as Name, 'other@yahoo.com' as Email
    UNION
    SELECT '4751' as ID, 666963 as Phone, '2014-11-14' as Called_date, 'some_name' as Name, 'some@gmail.com' as Email
    UNION
    SELECT '2896' as ID, 987987 as Phone, '2014-11-14' as Called_date, 'diff_name' as Name, 'diff@gmail.com' as Email
)t
```

Next, we need to use a CTE to return the row with the most recent Call_date for each Name:

```
;WITH CallData AS
(
    SELECT
        Id,
        Phone,
        Called_date,
        Name,
        Email,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Called_date DESC) AS RN
    FROM 
        ##CallData
)
SELECT
    Id,
    Phone,
    Called_date,
    Name,
    Email
FROM
    CallData
WHERE
    RN = 1
```

Finally, you can use FOR XML PATH and STUFF to join in the aggregated phone numbers for each name:

```
;WITH CallData AS
(
    SELECT
        Id,
        Phone,
        Called_date,
        Name,
        Email,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Called_date DESC) AS RN
    FROM 
        ##CallData
)
SELECT
    Id,
    Phone,
    Called_date,
    Name,
    Email,
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(t2.phone as VARCHAR(10))
              FROM ##CallData t2
              WHERE t.Name = t2.Name 
                    AND t.Phone <> t2.Phone 
              FOR XML PATH('')
             ), 1, 2, '') as Additional_phone

FROM
    CallData t
WHERE
    RN = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT id, Phone, Called_date, Name, Email
FROM(
    SELECT id, Phone, Called_date, Name, Email, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Email ORDER BY    Called_date DESC) as rn
    FROM yourTable
) a
WHERE rn = 1
```

Updated Answer:

```
SELECT a.id, a.Phone, a.Called_date, a.Name, a.Email, c.Phone as SecondPhone
FROM
(
    SELECT id, Phone, Called_date, Name, Email, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Email ORDER BY    Called_date DESC) as rn
    FROM yourTable
) as a
inner join (
            SELECT  name, Phone
            FROM 
                ( SELECT  name, Phone, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Email ORDER BY    Called_date DESC) as rn
                  FROM yourTable
                 ) b
            Where  rn = 2
            ) c on a.name = c.name

WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: How does this add the additional column `Additional_phone`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean "SQL Server", you can do this by creating an additional column for the additional phones that has a comma separated list.  Here is the idea:

```
select id, Phone, Called_date, Name, Email,
       stuff((select ', ' + t2.phone
              from table t2
              where t2.email = t.email and t2.phone <> t.phone
              for xml path ('')
             ), 1, 2, '') as Additional_Phones
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by Email order by Called_date desc) as seqnum
      from table t
      ) a
where seqnum = 1;
```